# Default shell in VS Code is not the same as gnome shell

Tags: linux, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, fedora

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

As seen in the above image, none of the regular commands work in vs code's integrated terminal. However the commands work perfectly fine in my gnome shell.

---

[image: Terminal Choices]

I tried to change the default shells in vs code to `/usr/bin/bash` and even `/usr/bin/sh` but both of them still give me the same problem.

[image: VS Code version]

This is the version of visual studio code which I am using (This problem also existed on v1.81.1)

Here is the output of neofetch

```
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
Host: VivoBook_ASUS Laptop X510UFO 1.0 
Kernel: 6.4.10-200.fc38.x86_64 
Uptime: 1 hour, 48 mins 
Packages: 2891 (rpm), 17 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 44.3 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX130
```

Comment: Is there a vscode setting to launch the shell as a **login** shell? That way your dotfiles get included.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install vscode via flatpak? This might be the reason. The flatpak version of vscode doesn't have access to the default terminal and your SDKs. Try installing vscode natively.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).